# beamer: \only and itemize

Tags: beamer, presentations

I would like to write somethings out of the itemize environment using \only, but to do so I need to add an item before \only<2>. Does anyone know how so solve this without adding this new item?

```
\documentclass[t,10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \only<1-> {
        Definition
        }
        \begin{itemize}
        % \item Useless
        \only<2> {
            \vfill \item Test 1 
         }
        \only<3> {
            \vfill \item Test 2
        }
        \vfill \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a [solution over at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925227/887412) - 
the syntax is `\item<only@1> item on first slide`

Comment: Thank you @IljaBek, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

Simply enclose the whole `itemize` in another `\only` so it sees the first `\item`:

```
\documentclass[t,10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \only<1-> {
        Definition
        }
        \only<2->{\begin{itemize}
        \only<2> {
            \vfill \item Test 1 
         }
        \only<3> {
            \vfill \item Test 2
        }
        \vfill \end{itemize}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Include the "Description" as part of the `itemize`, with some horizontal adjustment:

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title 1}
    \only<1-> {
    Definition
    }
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Useless
      \only<2> {
        \vfill \item Test 1 
       }
      \only<3> {
        \vfill \item Test 2
      }
      \vfill
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1->[]
      \hspace*{\dimexpr-\labelsep-\labelwidth}Definition

    \only<2> {
      \vfill \item Test 1 
     }
    \only<3> {
      \vfill \item Test 2
    }
    \vfill
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```